# Connection to networked computer works briefly, then "unable to connect" and "access denied"

Tags: windows-10, printer, sharing

I have a Brother MFC-7340 printer physically connected to my computer and have it shared so my wife can print to it from hers.  Both of us have Window 10.  She connects to my computer via wi-fi.  Everything has worked fine for a long time (a year maybe) and nothing has recently changed except that we have a new ISP and hence a new router.

Suddenly, she can't print.  We get various messages including "unable to connect" and "access denied."

The bizarre thing is this: If I uninstall the printer from her computer and reinstall it, everything works fine briefly.  The test page at the end of the installation wizard prints and she can print documents as usual.  But this only lasts for a few minutes...definitely less than an hour.  Then she starts getting the same error messages again.

Given this, the usual advice about checking that sharing is set up correctly isn't relevant.  It must be okay for even a single document to print.  The question is: What makes it stop working?

---

Update: In response to the two comments: My router doesn't seem to have a client isolation setting, and also my printer is not wireless, so I wasn't easily able to set a static IP address.

The idea that the problem was a dynamic change in the IP address did seem like like a good explanation for why things worked at first and then didn't though.  But while I was looking into this further, there was a new development.  Reinstalling the printer for the *n*th time on my wife's computer, sharing suddenly failed and I was asked for a username and password, even though I have always had password protected sharing turned off on my computer.  I set up an account for my wife on my computer, entered the username and password in the printer set-up wizard on her computer and...everything worked.

It's been several days now with no problems, so I'm convinced this is resolved.  I'm more confused than ever about what happened, though, and would welcome commentary.

Comment: Look in the Brother documentation for setting up Networking and give the printer a static IP on your network. It probably got lost in the change. Once set up with a static IP address, change the printer (in Devices, Printer Properties) to the new IP address

Comment: If you are using the Wifi from the ISP router check if it has a setting called "client isolation". Switch that OFF. It is likely new router has it enabled and the old router didn't.